# Parsing the IPV4 address from this string?

Tags: c++

I am using a networking API that gives me client IP's like this:

```
[::ffff:127.0.0.1]:54222:54222
```

I need to be able to detect if 2 clients are trying to connect from the same IP address. I do not allow more than one. For this, I need to parse the ipv4 portion of this string.

I'm just not sure how.

I can't just do a simple substring to get this.

Thanks

Edit: I cannot just use the entire string because that will  be unique per client rather than per ip address.

Comment: If the API is giving you IPv6 addresses like that, why not simply use the whole IPv6 address when checking for duplicates?

Comment: @GregHewgill the ports change even if it is coming from the same IP. I need a way to identify if it is a duplicate.

Comment: So just use the address part, and disregard the ports. I'm not quite sure I see the difficulty here.

Comment: @GregHewgill Does that also contain the MAC address of the client though? I do not want 2 people using the same connection to connect.

Comment: @Milo - the MAC address won't be known beyond the local logical network segment.

Comment: @admdrew oh, I was not aware of this, I thought IPV6 transmitted my PC's MAC to the server. Thanks!

Comment: Well, what you have there is an IPv4 address encapsulated in IPv6 syntax (presumably by the API you're using). As you can see, there's no MAC info in there.

Comment: I think you should first parse out the ip string, then conver it to sockaddr_in or sockaddr_in6, and then compare it.

Comment: For anyone thinking about doing this. IP address do not map 1:1 to computers. NATs can place everyone using an ISP on one address and a single computer can have multiple IP addresses (this is more common for IPv6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like...

```
/* parses 's' looking for a string between : and ] . If found, copies that
string into ipv4 and returns 1 */
int extract_ip4 (char *s, char *ipv4)
{
  char *p,*q;
  int i;

  q = strchr (s, ']');  /* search for ']' */
  if (!q)
    return 0;
  for (p=q;p!=s && *p!=':';p--);  /* search for ':' backwards from ']' */
  if (p==s)
    return 0;
  strncpy (ipv4,p+1,q-p-1);  /* copy portion of string to ipv4 */
  ipv4[q-p-1]='\0';
  return 1;             /* address found and copied */
}
```

Comment: i don't think this is the most C++ idiomatic way to do this